# access IEnumerable<Type>.GetEnumerator() from IEnumerable<Type>.GetEnumerator()

Tags: c#, generics, interface, ienumerable, explicit-implementation

please find the code there is error that getenuemrator() method is not defined in the class

```
private sealed class SelfAndBaseClasses : IEnumerable<Type>, IEnumerator<Type>, IEnumerable, IEnumerator, IDisposable
{
  private int state;
  private Type current;
  public Type type;
  private int initialThreadId;
  //public Type type;

  [DebuggerHidden]
  public SelfAndBaseClasses(int state)
  {
    this.state = state;
    this.initialThreadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
  }

  private bool MoveNext()
  {
    switch (this.state)
    {
      case 0:
        this.state = -1;
        break;

      case 1:
        this.state = -1;
        this.type = this.type.BaseType;
        break;

      default:
        goto Label_0055;
    }
    if (this.type != null)
    {
      this.current = this.type;
      this.state = 1;
      return true;
    }
  Label_0055:
    return false;
  }

  [DebuggerHidden]
  IEnumerator<Type> IEnumerable<Type>.GetEnumerator()
  {
    ExpressionParser.SelfAndBaseClasses d;
    if ((Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId == this.initialThreadId) && (this.state == -2))
    {
      this.state = 0;
      d = this;
    }
    else
    {
      d = new ExpressionParser.SelfAndBaseClasses(0);
    }
    d.type = this.type;
    return d;
  }

  [DebuggerHidden]
  IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
  {
    return this.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Type>.GetEnumerator();
  }

  [DebuggerHidden]
  void IEnumerator.Reset()
  {
    throw new NotSupportedException();
  }

  void IDisposable.Dispose()
  {
  }

  Type IEnumerator<Type>.Current
  {
    [DebuggerHidden]
    get
    {
      return this.current;
    }
  }

  object IEnumerator.Current
  {
    [DebuggerHidden]
    get
    {
      return this.current;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @digEmAll, this is decompiled code... the compiler doesn't mind gotos ;)

Answer (score 3):

Well, since you are implementing *both* the `GetEnumerator` methods explicitly, you could do this:

```
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    return ((IEnumerable<Type>)this).GetEnumerator();
}
```

But I have two questions:

1. Why do you wish to implement *both* the interfaces explicitly? That's not idiomatic at all. (EDIT: It's now clear why; this is generated code).
2. Is this code even written by a human? Looks suspiciously like what the C# compiler generates for iterator blocks. If so, how did you get your hands on it? A decompiler? Do note that it's common for decompilers to get tripped up on *correct* IL and produce C# code that doesn't compile.

EDIT: I took a look at the decompiled code for an iterator block with Reflector (I *suspect* this is the decompiler you are using?). It does appear to demonstrate this bug, i.e. the non-generic version decompiles as the clearly invalid:

```
return this.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Foo>.GetEnumerator();
```

EDIT:
The other fixes you need to get this to compile appear to be:

1. Change the accessibility of the `MoveNext` method to `public`.
2. Remove mentions of `ExpressionParser.` in the *generic* `GetEnumerator` method.

---

You can try it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/PZulo).

```
foreach (Type t in new SelfAndBaseClasses(0) { type = typeof(string) })
   Console.WriteLine(t);
```

Output:

```
System.String
System.Object
```

---

If you could better explain what you *really* want to do, we can help you better. It's not fun fixing incorrectly decompiled code. For example, if what you need is to write an enumerator for a type hierarchy, that would be *a lot* easier to do with an iterator block instead of going to the trouble of decompiling Dynamic LINQ.

Comment: thanks...yes, this is the decompiled code. and i have tried with the same code which you have posted but it doesn't work.

Comment: @user547621: On my machine, it compiles fine after the 2 other fixes. Of course, you need the appropriate `using` directives too: using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections;).

Comment: And it must be *nested* inside another class of course, you can't have a `private` top-level *type* as far as I know.

Comment: Error 3 'System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.SelfAndBaseClasses' does not implement interface member 'System.Collections.IEnumerator.MoveNext()'. 'System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.SelfAndBaseClasses.MoveNext()' cannot implement an interface member because it is not public.

Comment: @saurav: As I mentioned in my edit: "Change the accessibility of the MoveNext method to public."

Comment: @Ani Error 7 'System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.SelfAndBaseClasses' does not contain a definition for 'System' and no extension method 'System' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.SelfAndBaseClasses' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Ani i ve made changes according to you.. after this the error i ve mentioned above occured..

Comment: @saurav: It compiles fine on my machine, as it does on ideone. You can paste that code as is straight into your source file and it *should* compile. Your error must be somewhere else, I would think.

Comment: @ani IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return null; } but i want to have the output of IEnumerable<Type>.GetEnumerator() as a return

Comment: @saurav: The fix for that is in the first line of my answer. Anyway I've put that in as well. http://ideone.com/BFB5o

Comment: @ani can i knw ur email id. i need some assistance further.

Comment: @saurav: I would suggest you post another question on this site with your query. Try to be *clear* about what you want to do and what the end goal is. Cheers, good luck!